# Obj-C, dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm getting the following error...

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/--snip-my app.app/snip
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
```

Further on the thread I have...

```
dyld`dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, 
    char const**, char const**):
```

I added the MKStoreKit library, but didn't get this error when I ran my app earlier.
Since then I've changed my bundle ID for a new target as I'm creating a free version of my app.

Also, which seems mostly likely, I've added some version provisioning profiles.

I've no idea how to proceed ?

EDIT : This doesn't occur in the simulator only on my iTouch, plugged in.

Heres the code containing the iOS5 call
https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.m

Comment: Is your iPod Touch running iOS 5.0 or later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` was added in iOS 5.0.  You cannot use it on a device running iOS 4.

Comment: Here's the code, I thought this would be OK as it does an iOS5 check https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.m Any ideas ?